# Android String URL not working

Tags: php, android

I have PHP script that getting the requested name value to print the values. But it seems that when i try to use this

```
String URL_FEED = "http://brmhelpdesk.x10host.com/android_function/messages.php?name='" + NAME + "'"; //NAME = "1";
```

Its not working but when I use this

```
String URL_FEED = "http://brmhelpdesk.x10host.com/android_function/messages.php?name='" + "1" + "'";
```

Its working fine my problem is Why I cant make it work with declared String?

Java code

```
final String uid = user.get("id"); //tried for SQLiteDB
uidd.setText(uid); // tried for TextView
NAME = uidd.getText().toString(); //String declared String NAME = "";
```

Comment: I would guess `NAME` is not `"1"`, then.

Comment: What type of object is `user`? it seems `user.get("id")` is returning the empty string

Comment: `user` is from my SQLiteDBhelper, `HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();`

Comment: i already fix it thanks for the help guys its `user.get("uid");` not `("id")` :D